What are the ambient group $G$ and the hidden subgroup $H$ in Shor's order finding algorithm?
It is widely believed that Shor's order-finding algorithm is an example of hidden subgroup problem. However, there is a little trick here. The problem is what is the hidden subgroup in Shor's order finding algorithm?
In the order-finding algorithm, we try to find the period $P$ which is the smallest number satisfy $a^P=1 \pmod N$ and it is said in some book that the circuit will use $n$-qubit such that $Q=2^n\geq N^2$ so we have three numbers:$1.Q, 2.N$ 3.$\psi(N)$, while $\psi$ is the euler totient function.
So what is group here, since $f(x)$ is defined to be $f(x)=a^x\pmod N$. And $f(x)$ is constant on each coset of the hidden group. So this group should be $Z_{\psi(N)}$ we see that $f(P)=f(2P)=... $ the group should have $P$ cosets, the representation of them are $0,1,...,P-1$ since $a^0,a^1,...,a^{P-1}$ are different mod N.
And since $P|\psi(N)$, so the group should be $Z_{\psi{N}}$ the hidden group is $\{0,P,2P,...,\psi(N)-P\}$.
However, in that aglrotihm, $\psi(N)$ didn't appear at all. But may papers said the group is $Z_Q$,or $Z_N$, and the qft is acted on $Z_Q$ not $Z_{\psi(N)}$. So this makes the general framework of hidden subgroup problem doesn't fit the Shor's order-finding algorithm well.
To make things clearer, my issue is that in Shor's algorithm, it use a QFT with $e^{\frac{j2\pi}{Q}}$,but $Q$ is not the order of the group $Z_{\psi(N)}$, this is not consistent with the framework of the HSP, which use a QFT with $e^{\frac{j2\pi}{|G|}}$

Euler's totient function is usually $\phi$, not $\psi$.

TL;DR: There are a few slightly different ways to cast period-finding as a Hidden Subgroup Problem (HSP). The conceptually simplest formulation uses $G=\mathbb{Z}$, but it is not practical from quantum programmer's perspective since then $G$ has $\aleph_0$ elements$^1$. We can preserve conceptual simplicity with a finite group by setting $G=\mathbb{Z}_{rd}$ where $d$ is any positive integer and $r$ is the order of the given $a\in\mathbb{Z}_N^\times$. In the context of Shor's algorithm, $N$ is the integer to be factored and $a\in\{2,\dots,N-1\}$ is a randomly chosen integer. Anyway, this is of course rather unsatisfying since $r$ is what we're trying to compute. Finally, it turns out that we can arrive at a practical algorithm by replacing $\mathbb{Z}_{rd}$ with $\mathbb{Z}_{q}$ for a sufficiently large integer $q$. In this last formulation, period finding is no longer strictly speaking an instance of the HSP, but it is a good approximation (in terms of output probabilities). Below, I briefly describe the two formulations of period finding as an HSP.
Hidden Subgroup Problem
We say that a function $f:G\to X$ from a finitely generated group $G$ to a finite set $X$ hides the subgroup $H\subset G$ if $f(g_1)=f(g_2)\iff g_1g_2^{-1}\in H$. Then, the Hidden Subgroup Problem is the following: given access to an oracle for $f$, find a subset of $G$ that generates the hidden subgroup $H$.
Period finding problem
Given an element $k\in K$ of a finite group $K$, find the smallest positive integer $r$ such that $k^r=e$ where $e\in K$ is the neutral element of $K$. In Shor's algorithm $K=\mathbb{Z}_N^\times$, the multiplicative group of integers modulo $N$ whose order is $\varphi(N)$, the Euler's totient function.
Period finding as HSP in an infinite group
Set $G=(\mathbb{Z},+)$ and define $f:G\to K$ by $f_k(n)=k^n$. Note that $H=r\mathbb{Z}$ is a subgroup of $G$. Moreover, $k^{n_1}=k^{n_2}$ if and only if $n_1-n_2\in H$, so $f$ hides $H$. Finally, from the knowledge of a generating set for $H$, such as say $\{r\}$ or $\{6r, 35r\}$, we can efficiently recover the period $r$.
Period finding as HSP in a finite group
Set $G=(\mathbb{Z}_{rd},+)$ and define $f:G\to K$ by $f_k(n)=k^n$ as before.
In the context of Shor's algorithm, Lagrange theorem implies that $r$ divides $\varphi(N)$, so we can indeed choose $d$ so that $rd=\varphi(N)$ as anticipated in the question, but this is not necessary. Anyway, similarly to the infinite case, $H=r\mathbb{Z}_d$ is a subgroup of $G$. Moreover $k^{n_1}=k^{n_2}$ if and only if $n_1-n_2\in r\mathbb{Z}_d$, so $f$ hides $H$. Once again, from the knowledge of a generating set for $H$, such as say $\{r\}$ or $\{2r, 3r\}$, we can recover $r$.

$^1$ An even more important complication is that the dual group $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}$ of $\mathbb{Z}$ is the circle group $\mathbb{T}$, in contrast to the finite case where $\widehat{G}$ and $G$ are isomorphic.

the solution of hsp asume we know the order of the group but in fact we don't

The group is $G=(\{1,...,\phi(N)\},+)$, and the subgroup is $H=<r>$, where $r$ is the period of the function $f$.
